# Django - how to display all users that are present?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-queryset

I have created an attendance system in Django but I cannot seem to retrieve all users that are currently present.

My code is displayed below:

Models:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class is_Present(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    is_present = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class clocked_Time(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    signed_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
 # Displays admin attendance portal functions
def attendance_portal(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, f'Please sign in to mark attendance out')
        return redirect('login')
    elif not request.user.is_superuser or not request.user.is_staff:
        messages.warning(request, f'Must be admin to access this feature')
        return redirect('home')
    elif request.user.is_superuser:
        count_employees_all = count_employees()  # shows count of employees
        present_employee_all = present_employees()  # shows count present employees today
        present_employee_all_week = present_week_employees()  # shows count present employees in last 7 days

        # Gets the employees present today
        today = datetime.today()
        # Gets employees displayed and paginated
        user = get_user_model()
        user_list = user.objects.all()
        p = Paginator(is_Present.objects.filter(date=today).filter(is_present=True).select_related('user').values('user__username'), 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        users = p.get_page(page)

        try:
            users = p.get_page(page)  # returns the desired page object
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # if page_number is not an integer then assign the first page
            users = p.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # if page is empty then return last page
            users = p.page(p.num_pages)

        # this_week_emp_count_vs_date()
        # last_week_emp_count_vs_date()
        return render(request, "users/adminReports.html",
                      {'count_employees_all': count_employees_all, 'present_employee_all': present_employee_all,
                       'present_employee_all_week': present_employee_all_week, 'user_list': user_list, 'users': users})
    else:
        messages.warning(request, f'Error - please see logs for details.')
        return redirect(request, 'home')
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="card" style="margin: 2em; background: lightcoral;border: solid 3px dimgrey; padding-bottom: 30px; width: 50%">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 style="text-align: center"> Employee's Present Today </h4><br />
                {% for user in users %}
                    <table class="table align-left table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                  <td style="width: 25%;">{{ user.username }}</td>
                                 
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                {% endfor %}
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                    {%if users.has_previous %} {# whether the previous page exists #}
                        <a href="?page={{users.previous_page_number}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">&laquo;</button></a> {# link to the prev page #}
                    {% endif %}
                    <span>{{users.number}}</span> {# the current page number #}

                    {%if users.has_next %} {# whether the next page exists #}
                        <a href="?page={{users.next_page_number}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">&raquo;</button></a> {# link to the next page #}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

There is currently one user present today, and it seems to *grab* the user as it inserts one table row, however it does not allow me to grab the username etc (please see image)

[image: Image of current returned users]

Comment: Have you checked if `user.username` is a non-empty string?

Comment: Hi @AbhinavMathur, how would I test to see if user.username is populated or empty?

Comment: You could add a breakpoint while the model fetches the data, or add a condition to show the row `{{ if user.username }}`

Comment: I was able to resolve it - issue was in and around the area you mentioned.

I was able to debug this by just seeing what `{user}` returned, and it returned:
`is_Parent Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `user.username` was not getting referenced far enough. I was able to solve this by referencing using this:

```
user.user.username
```

[user.user.username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekX4W.png)